# How to download data from server using 2g network speed in android

Tags: android, networking, mobile

I am doing a practice on 2G, 3G and WI-FI for downloading data from server. For example, my data contains images and texts, if I use wi-fi/3G then there's no problem loading data to the UI. When I use a 2G connection, however, it may take some time to download data. How can I handle huge data when using a 2G connection? For example, when I use this URL which is taken from the Android Developer site...

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=android&sort=newest

How can I detect the network speed, amount of data coming down the pipe and warn the user?

Comment: You wait for the data to arrive at its slow speed.

Comment: Which answer do you expect? If you have low speed, you have to wait longer.

Comment: correct i should wait, but the thing is, if the data size is too high means we have to use thread or asynTask but as i said if the data is too high if the device couldn't manage the load in 2G, then how to handle it. I know how to find that device is connected with wi-fi, 3G/2G but how to handle the data in slow connection ??

Comment: @ManikandanKuppusamy the most obvious solution is to download only the most significant information and limit the items you get. For example `if(connectionDSL()) download 100 items; else if(connection2g()) download 5 items;`. Secondly : sacrifice something like images, for sure your user will understand why the image is not showing since they are using 2g connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are asking about. You should let the platform to handle the connection type, 2G, 3G, Wifi and etc. The connection should timeout with slow connection.

Are you doing network connection on UI thread? Network connections must not be on UI thread. Thus, they don't affect UI thread's performance.

You can load single url with WebView. Or, use a SDK, like Retrofit2, to download it in background thread and display the text in a textview.

Comment: am asking about, how to download the huge data from server using 2G connection, how to handle to get the huge json response in 2G network mobile using android programmatically??

Comment: what happened in your app when downloading large data with slow connection? connection time out? you can change the time out to what ever is suitable to your app.

If you have control over the large data on server, try to compress it on server and extract it at client side.